# bitbake fails on "bitbake nano"

Tags: arm, beagleboard, angstrom-linux, openembedded

I am trying to setup bitbake and openembedded in order to cross-compile code for angstrom 2009.x on devkit8000 (a beagleboard's clone). I have followed [this page](http://www.openembedded.org/wiki/Getting_started) but when I try

```
$ bitbake nano
```

I get

```
Loading cache: 100% |##############################################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 00:00:00
Loaded 1 entries from dependency cache.
ERROR: Error parsing /home/hnsl/stuff/openembedded/recipes/images/initramfs-kexecboot-image.bb: Could not inherit file classes/rootfs_${IMAGE_PKGTYPE}.bbclass                                                     | ETA:  --:--:--
ERROR: Command execution failed: Exited with 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it seems that I need to change version of Angstrom. Using

```
"DISTRO="angstrom-2010.x"
```

on stuff/build/conf/local.conf resolves this issue.